# Access a a nested class from inside another nested class

Tags: excel, vba

I have one main class with 3 nested classes looking like this:

Main class:

```
Option Explicit
Private m_Login As Object
Private m_Archivo As Object
Private m_Equivalencia As Object
Private Property Get Logins(ByVal Key As String) As Logins
    With m_Login
        If Not .Exists(Key) Then .Add Key, New Logins
    End With
    Set Logins = m_Login(Key)
End Property
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_Login = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set m_Archivo = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set m_Equivalencia = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_Login = Nothing
    Set m_Archivo = Nothing
    Set m_Equivalencia = Nothing
End Sub
Private Property Get Keys() As Variant
    Keys = m_Login.Keys
End Property
Private Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = m_Login.Count
End Property
Private Property Get Items() As Variant
    Items = m_Archivo.Keys
End Property
Public Property Get Archivos(ByVal Key As String) As Archivos
    With m_Archivo
        If Not .Exists(Key) Then .Add Key, New Archivos
    End With
    Set Archivos = m_Archivo(Key)
End Property
Public Property Get Equivalencias(ByVal Key As String) As Equivalencias
    With m_Equivalencia
        If Not .Exists(Key) Then .Add Key, New Equivalencias
    End With
    Set Equivalencias = m_Equivalencia(Key)
End Property
```

The three nested classes are, as you can see, Logins, Archivos and Equivalencias.

Now I'm trying to get the data stored in Equivalencias class from inside the Logins class.

When doing it from the main class I just need to write `Equivalencias(id).Property` for example, but I can't seem to call it from inside the nested class Logins.

How would I do it?

I need to do so because inside the Logins class I have this:

```
Public Property Get ModificacionCentro() As Boolean

    If Not Baja And Not Alta Then

        Select Case m_Site
            Case "GLORIAS" And m_Centro <> "Barcelona Glorias (AESP) (GRAN VÍA DE LAS CORTS CATALANES 866-872, BARCELONA)"
                ModificacionCentro = True
            Case "ILUSTRACIÓN" And m_Centro <> "Madrid Ilustración (AESP) (C/SANTIAGO DE COMPOSTELA, 94, MADRID)"
                ModificacionCentro = True
            Case "TÁNGER" And m_Centro <> "MARRUECOS TANGER SUCURSAL (AESP) (RUE IBN FOURMAT ANGLE CARNOT, TANGER 90000 (MAROC))"
                ModificacionCentro = True
            Case Else
                ModificacionCentro = False
        End Select
    End If

End Property
```

Right now I'm doing it hardcoded, but If I could access the other class I wouldn't need to, The code would be:

```
Public Property Get ModificacionCentro() As Boolean

    If Not Baja And Not Alta Then
        If Not Equivalencias(m_Site) = m_Centro Then ModificacionCentro = False
    End If

End Property
```

And I wouldn't need to hardcode everytime it the sites would change.

Comment: You are not using nested classes at all. You have a class with properties of the type of another class. If you need properties from the `Main` class in your `Logins` class then you'll have to pass a reference of your `Main` object to the `Logins` object and store it in an attribute of your `Logins` class.

Comment: @GeertBellekens could you help me out with an example of your comment? Or where to find information to actually work with nested classes? I'm pretty new with class oriented programming so any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Would it make sense to have Equivalencias reside inside Logins instead of Main? Then the graph would be: Main >> Logins >> Equivalencias were both Main and Logins would have access to Equivalencias.

Comment: Well that would mean duplicating the same equivalencias for all the logins.. It should work but that means a lot of duplicated data, right @Kostas K.?